# I want to display two different sucess message for two button in single lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, custom-button, helper

I have two button in same class one is Clone button,another is Renew button,now it is displaying only one sucess message for both button,but i want to display two different success message for two button,could you please help me.

This below code is same for two button:

```
if (rep.Error == '') {
    helper.showToast(component, event, helper);

    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
    "recordId": rep.OppId,
    "slideDevName": "related"
});

navEvt.fire();
}
```

And below code is showing both button success message:

```
showToast : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Show toaster - success messages only...");
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Opportunity Cloning",
            "message": "The opportunity has been Renew/cloned successfully.",
            "type":"success"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add extra parameters for the helper method showToast and set 'message' ,'title' dynamically from there.

```
showToast : function(component, event, helper,messageStr,titleStr,typeStr) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": titleStr,
            "message": messageStr,
            "type":typeStr
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },
```

Now this method can be used to show toast message for success and error messages.
For success message call

```
helper.showToast(component, event, helper,'message','title','success');
```

and for error notification change the last param to 'error' or 'warning' based on your need.

Please mark it as best answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tapas Tripathi